# What is the preferred way to concatenate sequences in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.3

What is the preferred way to concatenate sequences in Python 3?

Right now, I'm doing:

```
import functools
import operator

def concatenate(sequences):
    return functools.reduce(operator.add, sequences)

print(concatenate([['spam', 'eggs'], ['ham']]))
# ['spam', 'eggs', 'ham']
```

Needing to import two separate modules to do this seems clunky.

An alternative could be:

```
def concatenate(sequences):
    concatenated_sequence = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        concatenated_sequence += sequence
    return concatenated_sequence
```

However, this is incorrect because you don't know that the sequences are lists.

You could do:

```
import copy

def concatenate(sequences):
    head, *tail = sequences
    concatenated_sequence = copy.copy(head)
    for sequence in sequences:
        concatenated_sequence += sequence
    return concatenated_sequence
```

But that seems horribly bug prone -- a direct call to copy?  (I know `head.copy()` works for lists and tuples, but `copy` isn't part of the sequence ABC, so you can't rely on it... what if you get handed strings?).  You have to copy to prevent mutation in case you get handed a `MutableSequence`.  Moreover, this solution forces you to unpack the entire set of sequences first.  Trying again:

```
import copy 

def concatenate(sequences):
    iterable = iter(sequences)
    head = next(iterable)
    concatenated_sequence = copy.copy(head)
    for sequence in iterable:
        concatenated_sequence += sequence
    return concatenated_sequence
```

But come on... this is python!  So... what is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen `itertools.chain()`? I'm not sure it handles all of your intended use cases, though.

Comment: Don't be afraid of standard library imports. It is very likely that some other module (even from the standard library) will grab `functools` and/or `operator` anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead:

```
import itertools

def chained(sequences):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(sequences):
```

or, since you tagged this with [python-3.3](/questions/tagged/python-3.3) you could use the new [`yield from`](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) syntax (look ma, no imports!):

```
def chained(sequences):
    for seq in sequences:
        yield from seq
```

which both return iterators (use `list()` on them if you *must* materialize the full list). Most of the time you do not need to construct a whole new sequence from concatenated sequences, really, you just want to loop over them to process and/or search for something instead.

Note that for strings, you should use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead of any of the techniques described either in my answer or your question:

```
concatenated = ''.join(sequence_of_strings)
```

Combined, to handle sequences *fast* and correct, I'd use:

```
def chained(sequences):
    for seq in sequences:
        yield from seq

def concatenate(sequences):
    sequences = iter(sequences)
    first = next(sequences)
    if hasattr(first, 'join'):
        return first + ''.join(sequences)
    return first + type(first)(chained(sequences))
```

This works for tuples, lists and strings:

```
>>> concatenate(['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'])
'abcdefghijkl'
>>> concatenate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> concatenate([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)])
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

and uses the faster `''.join()` for a sequence of strings.

Comment: Whoa, that's some nice syntax! `yield from` is new in 3.3 right?

Answer (score 3):

what is wrong with:

```
from itertools import chain
def chain_sequences(*sequences):
  return chain(*sequences)
```

Comment: I don't think it is a question, but actually an attempt to answer. More explanation would have made that clearer.

Comment: It is in the answer section so it seems clear enough it was a proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`itertools.chain.from_iterable`**](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
import itertools

def concatenate(sequences):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sequences))
```

The call to `list` is needed only if you need an actual new list, so skip it if you just iterate over this new sequence once.

Comment: `concatenate(['a', 'b'])` will return `['a', 'b']` instead of `'ab'`, so this is not correct for my use case.  How would you figure out the sequence type?

Comment: @ToBeReplaced: string concatenation is best handled with `str.join()` in any case.

Comment: Why the "from_iterable" piece when chain(*sequences) works?